# Switching shared data sources based on condition in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2012

In SSRS how can we switch shared data sources based on condition.

I do have two shared data sources and one should be used when user access with admin access and other data sources should come into picture when user with other roles are using.

Can you guys help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new datasource setting a conditional connection string in the DataSource properties based on `User!UserID` running the report.

[image]

Use something like this:

```
=IIF(User!UserID = "YOURDOMAIN\Admin1",
"Data Source=MSSQLDB;Initial Catalog=DataBaseForAdmin",
"Data Source=MSSQLDB;Initial Catalog=DataBaseForNonAdmin"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi alejandro, That really helps.I have so many reports which are using only one Shared Datasource. I cant create a embedded datasources for each and every report. That was the problem. I want to create one more shared data source and switch it based on the condition.

Comment: @SureshKandi, Unfortunately there is no way to set shared datasources conditionally, the only option we have (Included in SSRS so far) is using an embedded datasource that changes dynamically its Connection String. However, in [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355461/Dynamically-Pointing-to-Shared-Data-Sources-on-SQL) is detailed a workaround by extending the SSRS built-in functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But i want get server and database instance details from database at run time & connect. This solution would be limited to only mention servers in IFF condition.